# Modify data values in a MySQL database by means of MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.0 on Xubuntu 14.04. I have tried to create a database, but I don't manage to insert values in the fields by means of MySQL Workbench. In fact in my template I have inserted some values, but when I access the database using the terminal I can't see any of the values.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

So far I have done a forward engineer and a synchronization, but it doesn't work. How can I modify the database directly from MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score -1):

Please use database -> forward engineer go next.. you will see success window.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP said "So far I have done a forward engineer and a synchronization, but it doesn't work". Please don't suggest things that have already been tried and don't work.